# Rails default select value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, selected

This is my first post, and I apologiese for repeating a previous question. But I'm new to Rails and need help from someone more experienced than I. I am trying to get a select box to select the database record.

My form reads:

I have tried adding
,params[:source]

And a few other methods which don't include the option for a select box. Could someone guide me as to what is missing to select my current record. Any info can be provided on request. I am using the current version of Rails on Mac OS. Thank you

Comment: My form reads <%= form.select(:source, options_for_select([['Thumbstack', 'Thumbstack'], ['Teacher', 'Teacher'], ['Google', 'Google'], ['Other', 'Other']]))  %>

Comment: `I am trying to get a select box to select the database record.` you mean you want database values in select box . is it ? need more explination

Comment: You should try to share some code, outlining your think process and where you get stuck. This is not a site to ask broad questions that could only be answered by teaching you an entire concept.

Comment: As @bo-oz mentioned, you need to come up with some code to get proper help from the community here. Give us the expected and actual behavior.

Answer (score -1):

As per the description mentioned in the post:

I am trying to get a select box to select the database record.

But you are passing statement values in options for select

```
<%= form.select(:source, options_for_select([['Thumbstack', 'Thumbstack'], ['Teacher', 'Teacher'], ['Google', 'Google'], ['Other', 'Other']])) %>
```

You need to change above one to the below mentioned:

```
<%= form.select(:source, options_for_select(ModelName.all.map {|h| [h.id, h.column_name]})) %>
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Options wrongly configured: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select